# Simple minishell, doesn't recognise "quit" to end program becasue of the way fgets works

Tags: c, token, fgets, fflush

I'm trying to write a minishell with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LINE_LEN  50
#define MAX_PARTS  50

int main ()
{
char* token;
char str[LINE_LEN];
char* arr[MAX_PARTS];
int i,j;

printf("Write a line: \n $:");
fgets(str, LINE_LEN, stdin);

while (str != "quit") {
    i=0;
    token = strtok(str, " \t\r\n");
    while( token != NULL ) 
    {
        arr[i] = token;
        printf("'%s'\n", arr[i]);
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL," \t\r\n");
    }
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Write a line: \n $:");
    fgets(str, LINE_LEN, stdin);
}   
return 0; 
}
```

It works correctly, but for the fact that when I type "quit", the program doesn't end. I guess it must be related with fgets and the fact that it incorporates EOF as another character at the end of string str, so when I compare it with "quit" it's not the same string.
I don't know which is the correct way to extract the \n character from the string I read from standard input. ¿Could anyone help me, please?

Another question I would like to ask is if it's a good idea to use fflush in this code or not.
Thank you

Comment: `while(strcmp(str, "quit\n") != 0) {`

Comment: Thanks, I had thought about adding \n to quit, but I'd rather like to know an efficient way of erasing  \n of the string I read with fgets.

Comment: I think it's more effective than erase perhaps.

Comment: `char *p = strchr(str, '\n'); if(p) *p = 0;` Read it all the way through the string, but there is no need to read it twice because he is cut out eventually in strtok this.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY When "quit" without a following `\n` appears in the last line of a text file, and we feed it into his shell by redirection, then it will not be recognized by your `strcmp`

Comment: @nodakai I think it's certainly true, but this program and is assumed to be input from the user it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess it must be related with fgets and the fact that it incorporates EOF as another character at the end of string str, so when I compare it with "quit" it's not the same string.

Nope.

First of all, `EOF` doesn't exist as a character, it's just a flag returned by some IO functions to tell you that the file finished while trying to read it.

What `fgets` leaves in the string is the newline character (if it stopped because of it and not because of EOF or of an error). You can easily remove it - if it's present - after acquiring the string:

```
size_t l=strlen(str);
if(l && str[l-1]=='\n')
    str[l-1]=0;
```

But most importantly, you are getting the comparison with `"quit"` wrong.

If you write `str != "quit"` you are performing a *pointer* comparison between `str` and `"quit"`, which will always fail since `str` and `"quit"` are distinct character arrays, and thus refer to different locations in memory. What you want is to compare the *content* of the two strings; in C, that is done with `strcmp`:

```
while(strcmp(str, "quit")!=0)
```

Comment: `while(strcmp(str, "quit")==0)` ?? See @BLUEPIXY's comments

Comment: @nodakai: what's the problem with it? The newline is already taken care of by the previous snippet...

Comment: @MatteoItalia possibly with this while condition control will come inside when string is "quit".. (it should be other way around)

Answer (score 2):

`fgets` will read `newline` character as well from statement below..

```
fgets(str, LINE_LEN, stdin);
```

So you have two option

1. use condition as below to compare 'quit':

   ```
   while (strcmp(str, "quit\n"))
   ```
2. Remove newline from input. Detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693826/2648826)

Comment: @Matteo ..thanks for edit.. I was struggling to format that while ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare strings by pointer like you do `str != "quit"`

Use `0 != strcmp(str,"quit")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str[4] == '\n')
    str[4] = '\0';
while (strcmp(str, "quit")!=0) {
```

Comment: It should check the return value of `fgets` Speaking a fine thing.